# passing json value through ashx handler: asp.net:

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

i am tring to fetch json object from an ashx handller to my js the code is as follow

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var path = 'Handler.ashx';

    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        dataType: 'json',
        }).success(function (data) {
            $('#content').html(JSON.stringify(data.a))
        });
</script>
```

and code for handller

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

    public string ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        string a = "hello world";
       return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a); 
    }

   public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
}
```

i m unable to fetch any output from the following code plz correct the code thnk u

Answer (score 0):

Using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` on a string just returns the string since there is effectively nothing to serialize.

Hence `JSON.stringify(data.a)` will not work because `data` is just the string "hello world", which has no property called `a` -- `data.a` will be `undefined`.